# Add numeric ID corresponding with a string ID in R

Tags: r

I need to create a new column with numeric ID's which is corresponding to a column with string ID.
I want it to look like this:

```
Numeric ID    String ID
1           2RRRRkbihdUTz/X
1           2RRRRkbihdUTz/X
1           2RRRRkbihdUTz/X
2           A09mqMKPnBgUf
2           A09mqMKPnBgUf
2           A09mqMKPnBgUf
2           A09mqMKPnBgUf
3           AaULuZXJWriMXM
3           AaULuZXJWriMXM
3           AaULuZXJWriMXM
```

What function can I use to generate the Numeric ID, which is the same for rows with the same string ID?

Comment: Try with `match` i.e. `with(dfn, match(StringID, unique(StringID)))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `match` to create the 'NumericID'

```
with(dfn, match(StringID, unique(StringID)))
```

---

Or another option is to convert to `factor` with `levels` specified as the `unique` values and then coerce it to `integer`

```
with(dfn, as.integer(factor(StringID, levels = unique(StringID))))
```

Comment: Thank you, the first function worked perfectly!